# FabricJs aligning an object to the left of another object

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I have an object that I need another object aligned left within.

```
  const handleToLeft = () => {
   const obj = c.c.getActiveObject();
   const canvasArea = c.c.getObjects()[0];

   obj.set({ left: canvasArea.left });
   obj.setCoords();
   c.c.renderAll();
   c.c.fire("object:modified"); 
 };
```

The code above works fine until I rotate 'obj' and call the function. At this point, the object gets cut off. Screenshot below:

[image]